# How to use the user control for these tabs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a web browser app for wp7. In that i have added some 6 tabs in it in the application bar menu items. But  now i want those 6 tabs in an user control page separately and if i click on tab 2 or any tab, it should work as it is now.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox"
     KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" />
<Grid x:Name="BrowserHost"
  Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
<shell:ApplicationBar>
<shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="1"
                                  Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="2"
                                  Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="3"
                                  Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="4"
                                  Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
</shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
</shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
private const int NumTabs = 4;

private int currentIndex;
private string[] urls = new string[NumTabs];
private WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[NumTabs];

public MainPage()
{ 
InitializeComponent();
ShowTab(0);
}

private void ShowTab(int index)
{
this.currentIndex = index;
UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "";
if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null)
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser;
    BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
}
for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++)
{
    if (this.browsers[i] != null)
    {
        this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
}

private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
    Uri url;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
    {
        this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
        this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid url");
}
}

private void TabMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int index = Int32.Parse(((ApplicationBarMenuItem)sender).Text) - 1;
ShowTab(index);
}
}
```

**Like the below browser has it.**
[image]

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot page, and associate your tap event handler function (something similar to your TabMenuItem_Click) to tap gesture on the pivot header.

Or simply use a pivot page with headers as 1,2,3,4 as per your question. In the eventhandler associated to event pivot_selectionchanged check for the pivot index and accordingly do your work.

I hope this was what you were looking for, else please explain your question further

Comment: No, i dont want it to be a pivot. I want the above like wp7 IE or UC browser is using to create new tab. I have added an image to my post.

Comment: the native browser doesnt support this UC. You will have to create this custom UC and click on the button/item will activate that control
or you can use a popup control and design it in the similar fassion

Comment: I know that i have to create my own User Control but am new to User Control, that's why i just need any samples that deals or similar to the above.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456394.aspx

here the author is using pop up to create an overlay screen in which he is taking the input. You will find plenty of pop up examples. Or you can also go for **Coding for fun toolkit** in which they have custom input prompts which you can use.

else, you may create a grid on the contentpanel and toggle its visibilty on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to create a user control there aren't so tough. In your project folder add new item as windows phone user control. In the new page created, type in your xaml code for the UI as you want (this is similar to any other xaml page) and its behavior in the code behind.

in your mainpage add the following line of code 
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProjectName.NameSpace">

then refer you control using this statement
<views:controlName> </views:controlName>

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything else